Thought experiment for understanding Lambert's cosine law
While there are a few questions about Lambert's cosine law on this site, I didn't find any answer proving it in a rigorous way.
According to Wikipedia,

Lambert's cosine law says that the observed radiant intensity ... from an ... ideal diffuse radiator is directly proportional to the cosine of the angle $\theta$ between the observer's line of sight and the surface normal; $I = I_0 \cos\theta$.

According to Introduction to Optics (1993) by Pedrotti & Pedrotti, that is because by changing $\theta$, the 'radiation cross section'  changes proportionally to $\cos\theta$.
Trying to understand why this law holds, I imagined the following thought experiment:
Assume that we have $N$ identical and very small lamps, each of power $\epsilon$, arranged regularly on a surface of area $A$ (similar to the atoms of a radiator, in some sense). Each lamp radiates in all directions equally. If we replace this array of lamps with a single lamp of the same type but of power $N\epsilon$, at large enough distances we should get the same angular profiles for radiation as in the previous case. It is true that in the first case the apparent area of the surface varies as $A\cos\theta$, but the number of light sources $N$ is constant. The apparent area varies just because the apparent distance between the lamps changes.
I think just saying that the 'radiation cross section' changes with the angle in a particular way doesn't explain the law (if by 'radiation cross section' the apparent area of the radiator surface at a given angle is meant). There are other assumptions and facts in play as well.
So, basically, I'm asking for a derivation of the law based on more fundamental laws of physics or geometrical considerations. A good derivation should reveal why my little thought experiment doesn't accord with the cosine law.

Lambert's cosine law is a good topic--my worst answer on this site is where I got it all wrong. Perhaps the down votes are because there is no "?" in the post? So a nice explanation of something is nice, but "off topic" as the mods say. idk.

@JEB, This is the first time somebody tells me on SE that I haven't asked a question because no question mark can be found in my post! Many times I pose the question implicitly. Here I have asked for a derivation of the law based on more fundamental laws of physics or geometrical considerations. A good derivation should also reveal why my little thought experiment doesn't accord with the cosine law.

I think you question is fine, but 2 close-voters think it's unclear what you're actually asking.

Okay. I'll rephrase some parts to make the question more clear.

"I'm asking for a derivation of the law based on more fundamental laws of physics or geometrical considerations." - there's the question! It's not directly on you @apanda if VTCers don't read the question thoroughly, but whether your question is closed does depend on them.

@controlgroup not everyone reads. For instance, I proposed the lack of a direct question being a problem, and then I get told (indirectly) that such a thing is outrageous! preposterous! Unprecedented, even. But it seems my "perhaps" was correct. maybe.

While I still can't derive the law quantitatively, understanding the behavior qualitatively actually seems to be quite easy.
In the thought experiment above, I considered one array of atoms (tiny lamps). But in reality, the radiator is composed of many layers (assuming it's crystalline, for simplicity). For the layer on the surface, our thought experiment is more or less valid. However, for photons emitted from atoms in deeper layers, the more the direction of propagation differs from the normal to the surface, the more likely it is that the photon will collide with other atoms and be absorbed by them.
